# Can't add time to date in Google go without parse error

Tags: go, go-templates

Works:

```
{{ $temp := timestampToDate $var.date }}
{{ $temp.Format 2006/01/02 }}
```

Doesn't work

```
{{ $temp := timestampToDate $var.date }}
{{ $temp := $temp.AddDate(0,-1,0) }}    
{{ $temp.Format 2006/01/02 }}
```

It says it can't parse the file with the second line but what's the issue? I'm using the command correctly as far as I can see.

Comment: You are declaring `$temp` twice (`:=`). Use `=` for assignment on the second line

Comment: Redeclared variable with `:=`.  See https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables. Totally unrelated to time or date.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a problem statement. What error do you see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first it may seem the problem is due to using `:=` syntax on an already existing variable, but that is not a problem, as this example illustrates:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{$temp := "aa"}}{{$temp}}
{{$temp := "bb"}}{{$temp}}`))

fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/W5D7ENdwW_1)):

```
aa
bb<nil>
```

But of course, if the variable already exists, you should use the `=` assignment, because the `:=` will create a new variable, which if happens inside another block (e.g. `{{range}}` or `{{if}}`), the changed value will not remain outside the block.

**The real problem is the function calling syntax:**

```
{{ $temp := $temp.AddDate(0,-1,0) }}
```

In Go templates you can't use the normal call syntax, you just have to enumerate the arguments, white-space separated, e.g.:

```
{{ $temp = $temp.AddDate 0 -1 0 }}
```

The error returned by [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Execute) indicates this:

```
panic: template: :3: unexpected "(" in operand
```

This is detailed at [`template/Pipelines`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Pipelines):

> A command is a simple value (argument) or a function or method call, possibly with multiple arguments:
>
> ```
> Argument
>      The result is the value of evaluating the argument.
> .Method [Argument...]
>      The method can be alone or the last element of a chain but,
>      unlike methods in the middle of a chain, it can take arguments.
>      The result is the value of calling the method with the
>      arguments:
>          dot.Method(Argument1, etc.)
> functionName [Argument...]
>      The result is the value of calling the function associated
>      with the name:
>          function(Argument1, etc.)
>      Functions and function names are described below.
> ```

Example:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "now": time.Now,
}).Parse(`{{$temp := now}}
{{$temp}}
{{$temp = $temp.AddDate 0 -1 0}}
{{$temp}}`))

fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jRmJ6jc6gdA)):

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 &#43;0000 UTC m=&#43;0.000000001

2009-10-10 23:00:00 &#43;0000 UTC<nil>
```

Comment: Superb. Thank you for the clarification on assignments and also how to properly call  functions. Clearly, I have a lot to learn about this syntax.